# I want to add an external library (TAD php) to my project in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I want to add an external library (TAD php) into my project that I made it using Laravel, but I couldn't that because I've never tried this before, this library is in GitHub and this is the link: https://github.com/cobisja/tad-php

please tell me how can add it to composer and install it because I am new in this Environment.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You attempted to add this library to trait and use in controller